# Solving a PDE with Method of Characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am currently trying to solve a PDE but am having difficulties. The PDE is:
$$(y+u)u_x+yu_y=x-y, \>\>\>\>u(x,1)=1+x$$
Now I found the Characteristic Equations:
$$\dot x(s) = y+z, \>\>\dot y(s)=y, \>\> \dot z(s)=x-y$$
Where $z(0)=u(x_0,y_0), \>\> x_0=x(0) \text{ and } y_0=y(0)$. The dot above is differentiation with respect to $s$. Then, I firstly solved for $y$ to get:
$$y(s)=e^s, \>\>y(0)=1$$
Thus we have our Auxiliary data confirmed. Now, This is where I get confused. If I sub in $y$ into the $z$ equation, this gives:
$$\dot z(s)=x-e^s$$Now I considered deriving this again, giving:
$$\ddot z(s) = \dot x(s)-e^s = e^s+z-e^s=z$$
Am I allowed to do this? I'm not sure if this is allowed, but if so then I can continue, solving for $z(s)$ and complete the question. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to do that and this is also a pretty nice trick to avoid the coupled ODEs.

Comment: A detailed solution of this problem is given in http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kersale/Teach/M3414/Notes/m3414_1.pdf  Example 1, page 21.